# setting action in form tag generates error "Validation of viewstate MAC failed..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am setting `action` in `form` tag and getting the error below:

*Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*

I have tried the following things:

1. Set machine config key in web.config.
2. Set EnableViewStateMac="false" in page
3. Set ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never"
4. Set EnableEventValidation="false"

but no luck.

Any guidance please.

Thakns for your help and sharing.

**Edit:**

Here is markup of my page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"
EnableViewStateMac="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Test.aspx" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share the markup from your project / view / form

Comment: Why is EnableViewStateMac set to false?  What happens if you set that to True?

Comment: CptSupermrkt, I just saw some replies recommeneding that that is why I tried but it did not work.

Comment: just saw you posted markup. will look into it.  my initial thought is that you should be able to set the form action without invalidating the ViewState.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? (5 years later)

Answer (score 4):

If you change the form tag and the markup for the button, you can accomplish the cross-page post.

Steps:

- Remove 'action' from form
- add 'PostbackUrl' to button

=========================================================

MSDN: **Cross-page Posting in ASP.NET**

overview : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.100).aspx

how-to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140(v=vs.100).aspx

=========================================================

```
<form id="aspnetForm" method="post" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Click" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to override the Render Event of the page to place the hidden fields for Encrypted Viewstate and Event validation on the top of the form.  This will ensure that these things get written out before anything that can submit the form.

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = 
      new System.IO.StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
  base.Render(htmlWriter);
  string html = stringWriter.ToString();
  string[] aspnet_formelems = new string[5];
  aspnet_formelems[0] = "__EVENTTARGET";
  aspnet_formelems[1] = "__EVENTARGUMENT";
  aspnet_formelems[2] = "__VIEWSTATE";
  aspnet_formelems[3] = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
  aspnet_formelems[4] = "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED";
  foreach (string elem in aspnet_formelems)
  {
    //Response.Write("input type=""hidden"" name=""" & abc.ToString & """")
    int StartPoint = html.IndexOf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + 
      elem.ToString() + "\"");
    if (StartPoint >= 0)
    {
      //does __VIEWSTATE exist?
      int EndPoint = html.IndexOf("/>", StartPoint) + 2;
      string ViewStateInput = html.Substring(StartPoint, 
        EndPoint - StartPoint);
      html = html.Remove(StartPoint, EndPoint - StartPoint);
      int FormStart = html.IndexOf("<form");
      int EndForm = html.IndexOf(">", FormStart) + 1;
      if (EndForm >= 0)
        html = html.Insert(EndForm, ViewStateInput);
    }
  }

  writer.Write(html);
}
```

Comment: thanks @Aghilas Yakoub, I just paseted this code insode in C# of default page. Later I check it was causing viewstate and eventarugments fields rendering just immidiately after form opening tag but error was still there. 

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: I'am happy to help you user576510, you can also  mark the form as disabled and then enable it in script once the load is complete:

  function enableForm() { 
      document.getElementById("form").disabled = false; 
  } 

  window.onLoad = enableForm(); (Another solution)

Comment: Aghilas Yakoub thanks again. Can you please also mention what is incorrect in above code you provided ? Or what changes I should do to make it working correctly. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help you, just delete the first code in Render method, and replace with this javascript code

Answer (score 1):

Add the below tags in your "Test.Aspx" and then try again

EnableViewStateMac="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableEventValidation="false"

Comment: thanks @Sathish Raja S.

Test.aspx will be secure page using SSL/ https. how these settings will effect it ? please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when the ViewState sent as part of the POST request does not match the controls collection.

The page receiving your request is `Test.aspx`

Set  `EnableViewStateMac="false"` on `Test.aspx` and your problem should get resolved.

Comment: thanks.

Test.aspx will be a secure page using SSL/ https. What effects EnableViewStateMac=fasle will do on it ? Please advice.

Comment: https is used to avoid a man in the middle attack. This setting will have no effect on it. Asp.net uses the MAC to validate control state(checks like no one set the text of a disabled control). These validation will not be done. It will mean you will have to validate the data you receive yourself. Note that controls save a lot of their data in the ViewState.